# When we look at an eavSetup what values are available for type and input?

Tags: magento2, eav, install-script

When creating an install script for Magento 2 what values are available for the type and input parts of `eavSetup->addAttribute()`?  Or where could I look to find out?

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'some_attr',
    [
        'type' => '',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Test Attribute',
        'input' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can find type and input value from the database **`eav_attribute`** table.

- **Type**

  - datetime
  - decimal
  - int
  - static
  - text
  - varchar
- **Input**

  - boolean
  - date
  - gallery
  - hidden
  - image
  - media_image
  - multiline
  - multiselect
  - price
  - select
  - text
  - textarea
  - weight

You can check for **`backend_type`** column value for your type case and **`frontend_input`** column for your input value for all attributes from this table.

You can check each attribute with list of different type and input.
You have get more idea to check this table.

Thanks.