# Magento 2 : Add Product Attribute Programmatically

Tags: magento2, php, product-attribute

How to create Magento 2 Product Attribute Programmatically with type : Text Area.

Comment: Here example - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/229270/9951
add attribute for Magento2 on the fly without setup

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Overview of Adding Product Attribute Programmatically

- Step 1: Create file `InstallData.php`
- Step 2: Define the `install()`    method
- Step 3: Create custom attribute

**Step 1:** Create file `InstallData.php`

We will start with the InstallData class which located in

```
app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Setup/InstallData.php.
```

The content for this file:

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

}
```

**Step 2: Define the install() method**

```
<?php

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

}
```

**Step 3: Create custom attribute**
Here are all lines code of `InstallData.php` to create product attribute programmically.

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, all the addAttribute method requires is:
The type id of the entity which we want to add attribute
The name of the attribute
An array of key value pairs to define the attribute such as group, input type, source, label…

All done, please run the upgrade script php bin/magento setup:upgrade to install the module and the product attribute sample_attribute will be created.

If you want to remove product attribute, you can use method removeAttribute instead of addAttribute. It will be like this:

**EDIT:**

for uninstall create the app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Setup/Uninstall.php.

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;

class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function uninstall(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute');
    }
}
```

Also you can follow below URL for creating custom product attribute.

URL : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically.html

Comment: I want to create a file upload attribute . What changes I have to do ? kindly guide

Comment: @ephemeral you can change the value of 'input' => '', You can read it here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/116829/2694

Comment: I have to replace 'int '  with ? on this link i didnt find for file upload :(

Comment: As special hint, dont let the field 'input' => '' blank. It will effect an error. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204420/the-configuration-parameter-formelement-is-a-required-for-custom-attribute-pro

Comment: hi @Prakash Patel, without installer can we create product attribute?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Please use Recurring instated of InstallSchema or InstallData. 
The recurring script is a script which will be run after the module setup script every time the command line php bin/magento setup: upgrade run.

Comment: @PrakashPatel, No my rquirement is, i want to create from custom api, without the setup install script, like here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257047/create-product-attribute-with-options-in-magento2-through-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

If someone interested from where those magic property are:

For all attribute types you can check `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapper::map` method. In `$this->_getValue($input, 'input', 'text')` - 'input' is a key which you can use in `eavSetup->addAttribute()`, - 'text' - is default value for 'input`.

Special for catalog attributes (product,category) you can check `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapperAbstract\PropertyMapper::map`.

Mappers for other attribute types in image bellow:

[image]

Note: if you don't specify some property in `eavSetup->addAttribute()` which don't have default value - `null` will be used.