# How to create attribute set and attribute in Magento 2 programtically

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to create attribute set and attribute. Then I want to assign the created attribute under the created attribute set.

I have created module.xml in app/code/Demo/Mymodule/etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
 <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
 </sequence>
</config>
```

and registration.php in app/code/Demo/Mymodule

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Demo_Mymodule',
    __DIR__
);
```

Then, I have created InstallData.php in app/code/Demo/Mymodule/Setup:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Mymodule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    private $attributeSet;
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
            $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
        } 

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

                // CREATE ATTRIBUTE SET 
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => 'Mydemo', 
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'sort_order' => 200,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();

                // CREATE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'new_text',
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'My Text',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'input' => 'textfield',
                    'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                    'source' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 5,
                    'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'attribute_set_id' => 'Mydemo',
            ]
        );  

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

} ?>
```

But still not working.

Comment: For create attribute Follow link:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162115/24878

Comment: What the error you are facing?

Comment: I am not facing any error,  but it's not showing any result.

Comment: The code which I share was ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used this code for creating new attribute sets and assign attribute into that attribute set.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    private $attributeSet;
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
            $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
        } 

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

                // CREATE ATTRIBUTE SET 
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME', 
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'sort_order' => 200,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();

                // CREATE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'attribute_id',
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'YOUR ATTRIBUTE LABEL',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                    'source' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 5,
                    'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'attribute_set_id' => 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME',
            ]
        );  

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with code. Please have a look.

Comment: I already implement same thing in my custom extension and it working fine. Have you run all magento command after implement this code?

Comment: Yes: php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: First you need to remove entry of your extension from setup_module table. then run the commands.

Comment: You mean that I have to create module from scratch again

Comment: No you don't. Just remove entry of your extension from setup_module table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68856/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-muneeb-syed).