# Create an Attribute Set and create a Product Attribute in Product Details Group for only One Attribute Set

Tags: module, product-attribute, custom, magento2.2.6, attribute-set

I asked a question here about this just over a week ago, but it took a little while to edit the post to include some code.

The original post and code can be seen [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262559/create-attribute-set-based-on-default-and-create-product-attributes-in-product-d)

I am able to create an Attribute Set based upon Default, create the Product Attribute and add this to the Product Details Group when either installing or upgrading a module.

My problem however is that Product Attribute is added to ALL attribute sets and not just the new attribute set that was created.  Looking in the MySQL tables I can see that my new Product Attribute is indeed linked to every Attribute Set.

Does anyone know how to stop the Product Attribute being added to all of the Attribute Sets EXCEPT the one that has just been created?  From what I have read, this should happen from using the 'attribute_set_id' while creating the Product Attribute, but this has not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a attribute to be added to all sets you will have to call explicitly the method `addAttributeToSet` which adds the attribute to an attribute set **and** a attribute group.
It is imho a litlle ilogic what happens in the EavSetup method `addAttribute()` but Magento's developer might have a reason for doing so :-)
If you add a parameter `group` the method `addAttribute()` fetches **all** attribute sets for the given `entity_type_id` and adds the attribute to them without taking care of your given`attribute_set_id`.

So the solution is the following (it worked for me in Magento 1 and as far as I know there were no major changes at this point):

1. create the attribute in the way you have done, but **don't use key 'group' in your attribute's parameter in method addAttribute()!**
2. add the following code in your setup script after `addAttribute()`:

   ```
   $attributeCode = 'your_attribute_code';
   $attributeSetName = 'Your Attribute Set Name or ID';
   $groupName = 'Your Group Name or ID';
   //$entityTypeId is already defined in your setup script otherwise you nedd to set that variable too
   $attributeId = $eavSetup->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $attributeCode);
   $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetName);
   $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $groupName);
   $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId,$attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, $attributeId);
   ```

I hope that helps.

Comment: HelgeB kindly provided a fully coded example on my other post that works perfectly.  Please follow the link above for the tested and working solution.