# Create a attribute set and add an attribute to it

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-attribute, magento2.2.2, attribute-set

How to create an attribute set set of the set attribute inherited from default and add a simple attribute to it that will be in the 'Content' group of the product

Use UpgradeData because magento 2.2.2

[image]

I found such a method, but I do not see the inheritance from the Default Attribute set

[How to create attribute set and attribute in Magento 2 programtically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201818/how-to-create-attribute-set-and-attribute-in-magento-2-programtically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below screenshot the code is already there to create attribute set from default attribute set.

[image]