# The configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for custom attribute product field

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, setup-upgrade

I just add custom attribute to my product like this:

```
<?php

namespace  Namespace\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
/* add this */
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements  UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
      EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
      \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3', '<')) {
          $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'dimension',
                [
                    'type' => 'decimal',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'Dimension',
                    'input' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => '',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => ''
                ]
            );
        }


        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

but i got an error when i tried to open the form to add product in Admin Page Catalog > Products > Add Product :

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The
>   configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for "dimension"
>   field.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution 1: You should delete attribute code `dimension` in `eav_attribute` table and recreate use `'input' => 'text'` in array. After then, reindex + clear cache.

```
[
    'type' => 'decimal',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'Dimension',
    'input' => 'text',
    'class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => '1',
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'unique' => false
 ]
```

Solution 2: You find a record with `attribute_code` = `dimension` on `eav_attribute` table, change value column `frontend_input` = `text`.

I hope it was helpful!