# How do I find all valid array keys for the EavSetup::addAttribute method?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, setup-script

When adding an EAV attribute in an install script (`Setup/InstallData.php` or `Setup/UpgradeData.php`), the third argument to the `addAttribute` method is an array of information customizing the created attribute. An example (from [this related question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116792)) is shown below:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'some_attr',
    [
        'type' => '',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Test Attribute',
        'input' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
    ]
);
```

A lot of those array values are left blank, and many of them seem applicable only to certain entity types (e.g. the `used_in_product_listing` key probably wouldn't be added on a `customer_address` attribute).

Where can one find the range of possible keys for this array? Is it dependent on the attribute's entity type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addAttribute` method in `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup.php` passes the array through a `PropertyMapperInterface`:

```
public function addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
    {
        $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);

        $data = array_replace(
            ['entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId, 'attribute_code' => $code],
            $this->attributeMapper->map($attr, $entityTypeId)
        );
```

[github link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e411c1d7859684ffa946d3197b75eadfdc6d1027/app/code/Magento/Eav/Setup/EavSetup.php#L807)

In the `Eav` module's `di.xml`, we find that the implementation preference for `PropertyMapperInterface` is `Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapper\Composite.php`. As the class name suggests, this class simply aggregates the functionality specified by `PropertyMapperInterface` implementations in other modules:

```
public function map(array $input, $entityTypeId)
{
    $data = [];
    foreach ($this->propertyMappers as $class) {
        if (!is_subclass_of($class, \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapperInterface::class)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                'Property mapper ' .
                $class .
                ' must' .
                ' implement \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapperInterface'
            );
        }
        $data = array_replace($data, $this->objectManager->get($class)->map($input, $entityTypeId));
    }
    return $data;
}
```

[github link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e411c1d7859684ffa946d3197b75eadfdc6d1027/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup/PropertyMapper/Composite.php#L44)

These other implementations are injected into the `Composite` class's constructor, again, through dependency injection. For example, all EAV attributes receive treatment from `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapper.php`, due to another entry in `Eav`'s `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapper\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="propertyMappers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapper</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

[github link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e411c1d7859684ffa946d3197b75eadfdc6d1027/app/code/Magento/Eav/etc/di.xml#L39)

The implementation looks something like this:

```
public function map(array $input, $entityTypeId)
{
    return [
        'attribute_model' => $this->_getValue($input, 'attribute_model'),
        'backend_model' => $this->_getValue($input, 'backend'),
        'backend_type' => $this->_getValue($input, 'type', 'varchar'),
        ...
    ]
}
```

[github link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e411c1d7859684ffa946d3197b75eadfdc6d1027/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup/PropertyMapper.php#L22)

Note how the keys specified in the `array $attr` of the original `addAttribute` method map to slightly different column names in the database.

What about `used_in_product_listing`? Sure enough, scouring through the relevant modules' `di.xml` files, one can find that `Magento\Catalog` appends a `PropertyMapperInterface` to the `Composite`, and in its implementation resides the line:

```
'used_in_product_listing' => $this->_getValue($input, 'used_in_product_listing', 0),
```

[github link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e411c1d7859684ffa946d3197b75eadfdc6d1027/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Setup/PropertyMapper.php#L40)

Later on in the `EavSetup` class's `addAttribute` method, descending a bit into private internal method calls, one can find that some of these database columns reside not in the main `eav_attribute` table, but in an additional data table specified by the `eav_entity_type` table's `additional_attribute_table` column. In the case of `used_in_product_listing`, it is in fact a column in the `catalog_eav_attribute` table.

Determining the actual function of each of these array keys is an entirely different exercise. However, with this general method, developers can at least easily determine the scope of configuration options when programatically creating a new attribute.